# Combine Two Properties From Entity In List And Flatten It With Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, flatten

I have a list of entities in this structure below.  How can I create a distinct list of `List<int>` of all the `AwayTeamId` and `HomeTeamId` with linq in one call?  I know I can do a select many on the HomeTeamId and get all of those, but I also need the AwayTeamId included.

```
class Game {

   int AwayTeamId;
   int HomeTeamId;

}
```

Comment: So if you had 5 `Game` instances you'd have 10 entries in your new list (assuming they were all distinct)?

Comment: Yep that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uriil's answer may be even shorter:

```
var result = games
    .SelectMany(game => new[] { game.AwayTeamId, game.HomeTeamId })
    .Distinct()
;
```

No need for additional .Select and lists creation for every Game record.

Comment: Nice. What about the call to `Distinct` though?

Comment: There wasn't strict requirement for removing distinct values. Just the "all the AwayTeamId", but distinct can remove non-unique and therefor we get not "all".

Comment: Well, the asker accepted an answer that removes dupes, and the other answer also removes dupes. Doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Yes distinct is necessary, but just add Distinct() to it.

Comment: I don't like this because it causes a heap array allocation (`new[]`).

Comment: @Dai, you're absolutely right. It's faster than Uriil's answer that it was compared with (5.57±0.10 vs 8.99±0.12), but much slower that union by Rob (3.53±0.07).

Comment: @Stan i'm curious about your complextiy values, how do you calculate these?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are just after a flat list of all the team ids (home or away), then how about UNIONing two SELECTs?

```
var teamIds = games.Select(g => g.HomeTeamId).Union(games.Select(g => g.AwayTeamId));
```

[`games` being the list of `Game` entities in my example above]

Comment: Just a thought - what if the there are duplicate home or away team ids? So (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1) - wouldn't the `Union` filter out the duplicate AwayId but not the duplicate HomeId?

Comment: @DanielKelley - no - it distincts the entire resulting list, thus de-duping items in either list, or the union of the lists.

Comment: @RobLevine Interesting. I have learned something new today - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
var result = entityContext.ListOfGames
      .Select(p=>new List<int>{p.AwayTeamId, p.HomeTeamId})
      .SelectMany(p=>p).Distinct();
```

If it's LINQ to ENTITY you will need to call `.ToList()` after ListOfGames, to make this solution works